# Show only year in citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Currently, I am using this bibliography style:

```
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

To cite, I just use `\cite{stone2010}`. This citation looks something like this:

> ...some text[Stone, 2010]. Some more text.

Now, I would like to achieve the following: in some sentences, I already mention the name of the author(s). In that case, I would like for the citation to only contain the year and not the name of the author(s). Let me explain this with an example. Currently, I have this:

```
...this was developed by Stone et al.\cite{stone2000}.
```

> ...this was developed by Stone et al.[Stone et al., 2000]

What I would like to have is:

> ...this was developed by Stone et al. [2000].

How can I get this?

Comment: Have you considered loading the `natbib` package (possibly with the option `square`, for square brackets) and writing `\dots this was developed by \citet{stone2000}.`? With the `apalike` bibliography style in use, this input should generate "this was developed by Stone et al. [2000]."

Comment: I've re-posted an expanded version of my comment as an answer.

Comment: Is there a way to invert the command? \cite stays standard for name and year, while \citep calls for only the year? I have been looking for this for a long time and now my thesis is almost done and would have to change all \cite to \citep for using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `square` (to encase years in square brackets) and (b) use `\citet` to generate "textual" citations.

Actually, if the `natbib` package is loaded, `\cite` defaults to `\citet`; you'll thus get textual citation call-outs automatically if you keep using `\cite`. To generate "parenthetical" citation call-outs -- of the type "[Stone et al., 2000]" -- you'll need to type `\citep{stone2000}`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{stone2000,
   author  = "Flint Stone and Alexandra Alright and Daniel Doubts",
   title   = "Thoughts",
   journal = "Circularity Today",
   year    = 2000,
   volume  = 1,
   number  = 2,
   pages   = "3-4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\dots\ this was developed by \citet{stone2000}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```